# How to count consecutive characters?

Tags: python-3.x

Need to find the count of each consecutive character in a row.
Ex: aaaabbBBccaa
output: a4b2B2c2a2

The character may repeat but need to count only consecutive ones. I also need to maintain the original sequence.
I tried to do this by code below but it doesn't work.

```
l = input()
counter = dict()
if l.isalpha() == True:
   for letter in l:
      if letter in counter:
         counter[letter] += 1
      else:
         counter[letter] = 1
   for this_one in list(counter.keys()):
      print(this_one,counter[this_one],sep ="",end="")
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution if you are interested in the `while` loop mechanics :

```
l = 'aaaabbBBccaazzZZZzzzertTTyyzaaaAA'
output = ''

index = 0
while index < len(l):
    incr = index
    count = 1
    output += l[incr]
    while incr < len(l)-1 and l[incr]==l[incr+1]:
        count += 1
        incr += 1
        index += 1
    output += str(count)
    index += 1

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` allows you to express this quite concisely using a generator expression.

```
from itertools import groupby

''.join(f'{x}{len(list(y))}' for x, y in groupby('aaaabbBBccaa'))
# outputs:
'a4b2B2c2a2'
```